# Routes are not working in react when I am using in given format

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

- Pages are not rendering when I am changing route
- PublicRoutes called in app.js inside of BrowseRouter and Switch as well but nothing is happening

  ```js
   const routes = [
     { path: "/", component: Home },
     { path: "/forgototp", component: ForgotOtp },
     { path: "/forgotpassword", component: ForgotPassword },
     { path: "/newpassword", component: NewPassword },
     { path: "/product", component: Product },
     { path: "/signin", component: SignIn },
     { path: "/signup", component: SignUp },
   ];

   function PublicRoutes() {
     return routes.map(({ path, component }) => (
       <Route exact={true} key={path} path={path} component={component} />
     ));
   }
  ```

  ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have just a little error here. The PublicRoutes function should return a valid React Element and you are returning an array of elements. You can just use a [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) in the PublicRoutes function like this and it should work:

```
function PublicRoutes() {
  return (
    <>
      {routes.map(({ path, component }) => (
        <Route exact key={path} path={path} component={component} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Checkout a working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-react-router-v5-basic-example-f4m99?file=/src/App.tsx:870-1053)